# Do you need to change 'rpcuser' and 'rpcpassword' for each bitcoind node you run?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin.conf, authentication

When running several `bitcoind` nodes on different machines, can I simply keep the same `bitcoin.conf` file everywhere, or do I need to ensure that a different `rpcuser` is set up for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rpc user/pass is only needed if you're planning to access the node via RPC. If you're running Armory on top of it, for example, that requires RPC and hence you would need it (Armory auto-creates the rpcuser/password for you, though).

If you're running a node and don't need the RPC functionality, no, you don't need those parameters set.

Comment: Thanks v much Jimmy. This means I can keep same config file.